# What is the problem in the "Tetris" game problem given below?

Tags: python, tetris

So basically when I start the program everything looks fine, until I try to move the figure.

When I try to move figure `left` or `right` ,then I get the following error:

```
"local variable 'j' referenced before assignment".
```

When I try to move the figure `down`, then another error pops up

```
"'Tetris' object has no attribute 'width'".
```

I already searched up the code for grammatical errors but found nothing.

Code:

```
import pygame
import random 

colors = [
    (0,0,0),
    (0,240,240),
    (0,0,240),
    (240,0,160),
    (0,240,0),
    (160,0,240),
    (240,0,0)
]



class Figure:
    x = 0
    y = 0

    Figures = [
      [[1, 5, 9, 13], [4, 5, 6, 7]],
      [[1, 2, 5, 9], [0, 4, 5, 6], [1, 5, 9, 8], [4, 5, 6, 10]],
      [[1, 2, 6, 10], [5, 6, 7, 9], [2, 6, 10, 11], [3, 5, 6, 7]],
      [[1, 2, 5, 6]],
      [[6, 7, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6, 10]],
      [[1, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 5, 9], [4, 5, 6, 9], [1, 5, 6, 9]],
      [[4, 5, 9, 10], [2, 6, 5, 9]]
    ]

    def __init__(self, x_coord, y_coord):
        self.x = x_coord
        self.y = y_coord
        self.type = random.randint(0,len(self.Figures)-1)
        self.color = colors[self.type+1]
        self.rotation = 0

    def image(self):
        return self.Figures[self.type][self.rotation]

    def rotate(self):
        self.rotation = (self.rotation + 1) % len(self.Figures[self.type])

class Tetris:
    height = 0
    width = 0
    field = []
    score = 0
    state = 'start'
    Figure = None

    def __init__(self, _height, _width):
        self.height = _height
        self.width = _width
        self.field = []
        self.score = 0
        self.state = 'start'
        for i in range(_height):
            new_line = []
            for j in range(_width):
                new_line.append(0)
            self.field.append(new_line)
        self.new_figure()

    def new_figure(self):
        self.Figure = Figure(3, 0)

    def go_down(self):
        self.Figure.y += 1
        if self.intersects():
            self.Figure.y -= 1
            self.freeze()

    def side(self, dx):
        old_x = self.Figure.x
        edge = False
        for i in range(4):
            for j in j in range(4):
                p = i * 4 + j
                if p in self.Figure.image():
                    if j + self.Figure.x + dx > self.width -1 or \
                        j + self.Figure.x + dx < 0:
                        edge = True
        if not edge:
            self.Figure.x += dx
        if self.intersects():
            self.Figures = old_x

    def left(self):
        self.side(-1)

    def right(self):
        self.side(+1)

    def down(self):
        while not self.intersects():
            self.Figure.y += 1
        self.Figure.y -= 1
        self.freeze()

    def rotate(self):
        old_rotation = self.Figure.rotation
        self.Figure.rotate()
        if self.intersects():
            self.Figure.rotation = old_rotation


    def intersects(self):
        intersection = False
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                p = i * 4 + j
                if p in self.Figure.image():
                    if i + self.Figure.y > self.height - 1 or \
                        i + self.Figure.y < 0 or \
                        self.field[i + self.Figure.y][j + self.Figure.x] > 0:
                        intersection = True
        return intersection

    def freeze(self):
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                p = i * 4 + j
                if p in self.Figure.image():
                    self.field[i + self.Figure.y][j + self.Figure.x] = self.Figure.type
        self.break_lines()
        self.new_figure()
        if self.intersects():
            self.state == 'gameover'

    def break_lines(self):
        lines = 0
        for i in range(1, self.height):
            zeros = 0
            for j in range(self.wifth):
                if self.field[i][j] == 0:
                    zeros += 1
            if zeros == 0:
                lines += 1
                for i2 in range(i, 1, -1):
                    for j in range(self.width):
                        self.field[i2][j] = self.field[i2 - 1][j]
            self.score += lines ** 2



pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((380, 670))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tetris by Calvin')

done = False
fps = 2
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
counter = 0
zoom = 30

game =  Tetris(20, 10)
pressing_down = False
pressing_left = False
pressing_right = False

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)

while not done:
    if game.state == 'start':
        game.go_down()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    game.rotate()
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    pressing_down = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    pressing_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    pressing_right = True


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pressing_down = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressing_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pressing_right = False

        if pressing_down:
            game.down()
        if pressing_left:
            game.left()
        if pressing_right:
            game.right()

    screen.fill(color=WHITE)
    for i in range(game.height):
        for j in range(game.width):
            if game.field[i][j] == 0:
                color = GRAY
                just_border = 1
            else:
                color = colors[game.field[i][j]]
                just_border = 0
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [30+j*zoom, 30+i*zoom, zoom, zoom],just_border)

    if game.Figure is not None:
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                p = i * 4 + j
                if p in game.Figure.image():
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, game.Figure.color,
                                     [30+(j + game.Figure.x)*zoom, 30+(i+ game.Figure.y)*zoom, zoom, zoom])

    gameover_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 65, True, False)
    text_gameover = gameover_font.render("Game Over!\n Press Esc", True, (255, 215, 0))

    if game.state == "gameover":
        screen.blit(text_gameover, [30,250])

    score_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
    text_score = score_font.render("Score: " + str(game.score), True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_score, [0,0])


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)



pygame.quit
```

Comment: the `side` method contain a line `for j in j in range(4)`, Is this intentional or a mistake?

Comment: `self.wifth` - shouldn't this be `self.width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 77 you wrote

```
    for j in j in range(4):
```

instead of

```
    for j in range(4):
```

and in line 134

```
    self.wifth
```

should be replaced by

```
   self.width
```

Comment: thank u so much. But it did not fix the error when I try to go down, it says "list index out of range" Anyway thank you for your time :)